# How to implement a network proximity checker in Unity using LLAPI?

Tags: unity, c#, networking, unityscript, unity-networking

I'm trying to implement a network proximity checker using my own functions in Unity, using LLAPI. How can I implemnet a network proximity checker, with similar functionalities than the ones in the HLAPI proximity checker?